# Adding translation files to install profile?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, installation-profiles

I am building a Drupal installation profile to make deployment of my site easier, ideally I would like to include the translation files to the install profile as well. But apart from adding the core translation files download to the makefile, is there a way to somehow add the translation files for the modules that are in use and for the custom fields as well?

Ideally I would like to add the needed .po files to the makefile or the profile's .install-file. Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://zgadzaj.com/drupal-installation-profile-with-multiple-languages ?

Also you can try to export it with Features

> Features
>
> The features module enables the capture and management of features in
>   Drupal. A feature is a collection of Drupal entities which taken
>   together satisfy a certain use-case.

And for more especific export data

> UUID Features Integration
>
> The UUID Features Integration module provides a mechanism for
>   exporting content (nodes, taxonomy, fields) into a features module.
>   What's that you say? You thought features was only for configuration?
>   This module is meant to be used in the cases where certain pieces of
>   content straddle the line between pure content and configuration.
>   You've to configure the entity types / bundles to be exportable. Read
>   the [Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2261719) for further information.